# Highcharts custom styling connect and label

Tags: highcharts

How to I custom donuts in highcharts with, each start point connect label have a circle, and style the connect line, and hidden the lower value.
I using highcharsjs

like this one

[image]

Comment: need more explanations to get answer

Comment: may be you can use the [softConnector](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.softConnector) property?

Answer (score 1):

In Highcharts you can only edit softness of connector and color/length. If you want to change that, then you need to overwrite `drawDataLabels` function for pie series. Or update `series.data[index].connector` path after rendering to fit your needs.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yzob09ks/

```
function redrawConnectors() {
     var chart = this,
         d;

    Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(point, i) {
        if(point.connector) {
            d = point.connector.d.split(' ');
            d = [d[0], d[1], d[2], d[10], d[11], d[12]];
            point.connector.attr({
                d:  d
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Note: Demo just shows how to change default behavior for connectors, now just render proper shape you want to.